# Pass data through Named Function using jQuery .on() Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

This can be easily achieved with the use of an anonymous function but is there a better way to pass data through a named function using jQuery `.on()` method?

```
$('#browser .next').on( 'click', function() {

    APP.search.page('next');

});
```

But removing anonymous functions from the event is difficult.

When using a named function I can access the data by first passing the event and then accessing the data within the event (event.data.page) but that makes for some messy code within the function.

```
$('#browser .next').on( 'click', {  page: 'next'  } , APP.search.page );
```

Is there any better way to pass the data without having to access it through the event as can be achieved in the anonymous function?

Comment: you can use `$(this)` if you use named function for sure

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bind method

```
$('#browser .next').on(
   'click',
    APP.search.page.bind(APP.search.page,
   'next')
);
```

or

You can pass as parameter any type of data

```
$('#browser .next').on(
   'click',
    APP.search.page.bind(APP.search.page,
   {some: 'value'})
);
```